# Remove trailing ~ from files

Tags: linux, rename

I have a list of files ending with `~`

I find them with

```
find /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ -type f -name "*.*~"
```

How can I  eliminate that `~`

Comment: Do you want to rename the files or eliminate the final `~` from the list of you generate?

Comment: @Anthon no just eliminate the final ~, It's resolved with the command of Chris Down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ -type f -name '*.*~' \
    -exec sh -c 'for arg do mv -- "$arg" "${arg%\~}"; done' _ {} +
```

- Passing `_` first sets `$0` to `_`, which would otherwise have taken your first filename.
- Using `+` instead of `;` tells `find` to pass as many filenames as it can to a single command instead of executing a new shell for each file.

Comment: BTW: `-name '*~'` is more correct. Otherwise you get files whose "_extension_" ends with `~`. That is to say , `README~` won't get renamed.

Comment: @Otheus This is the same pattern provided by the OP, which I would not advise changing (since I guess they already checked it works for their use case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename`:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ -type f -name "*.*~" -exec rename 's/~$//' {} \;
```

Comment: Never heard of the rename command. That's cool. Thanks. PS, "part of the until-linux-ng package". But the way you use it is not documented in the version I have (dated 2000). From how it's documented, I would do (as part of the find -exec) `rename "~" "" {}`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$(find /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ -type f -name '*.*~')"
do
    mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e 's/~//g')"
done
```